# Grails Gebish Functional Tests for page created with javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, selenium, htmlunit, geb

i am writing a test class

```
class ListOfProjectsSpec extends GebReportingSpec{

    def "project dashboard filters are instantiated correctly" () {
        given:
        at ProjectIndexPage

        expect:
        projectTable != null
    }

}
```

to test functionality of my `ProjectIndexPage`.

```
class ProjectIndexPage extends ProjectsCategoryPage{

    static at = {
        $("title").text() == "Title"
    }

    static content = {
        projectTable {
            $("table.dynamic-projectTable")
        }  
    }
}
```

(i cleaned up a lot of code to show the simplest case only).

**complication**

the class `dynamic-projectTable` is added at runtime to the table with jquery/javascript in as an acessor for filters on the page.

```
<g:javascript>
    $(
        $('#projectTable').addClass('dynamic-projectTable');
    });
</g:javascript>
```

**error**

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: geb.error.RequiredPageContentNotPresent: 
The required page content 'projectTable- SimplePageContent (owner: ProjectIndexPage, args: [],
value: null)' is not present
```

**additional info**

when looking at the html output of the spock test it is clear that the `dynamic-projectTable` class is not added (as are all other actions performed by the `$()` jquery call - i removed them here to make the example more readable)

**i tried**

```
// calling the document.ready function explicitly in my test cases
when:
$("document").ready()
```

**enabled javascript**

```
driver = {
    HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
    driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    driver
}
```

but nothing seems to work.
any input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve it by explicityly re-enabling javascript in the testSpec:

```
def setup() {
    if (driver instanceof HtmlUnitDriver) {
        driver.javascriptEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pages built by javascript often require Geb to wait for the content to be rendered.
See http://www.gebish.org/async for details.

Basically, I'd try explicitly waiting in your spec code:

```
waitFor { projectTable }
```

Waits can also be configured on the page content:

```
projectTable(wait: true) {
    $("table.dynamic-projectTable")
}
```

Comment: thank you for the hint, i changed this & it makes my tests more reliable. although the solution for the actual question was something else (see my own answer).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid issues like this it is better to define more applicable at checks.

In your example you have used:

```
 static at = {
     $("title").text() == "Title"
 }
```

Try checking for something which will be used in the tests. E.g A form element. I would also use a waitFor closure in the at checker so all pages after a to call will be ready for testing.

```
static at = {
     waitFor { $('#projectTable').@class.contains("dynamic-projectTable") }
 }
```

Comment: thank you for the hint, i changed this & it makes my tests more reliable. although the solution for the actual question was something else (see my own answer).